# Zend Studio 9 : Where are SVN logs

Tags: svn, zend-studio

I'm trying the integrated Zend Studio Subversion features.

I'm  searching for a way to see what have been updated when I run a "svn up". In tortoise, when I update, I can see what files arrived and double click on one to see what changed.

There is nothing in the console view.

Thank you for answers, 
see you !

Comment: Most probably you can see that in the Console. Press Alt + Shift + Q and then C.

Comment: There is indeed a SVN view in the console but it keeps empty, nothing is printed in it. either when updating nor commiting. http://img541.imageshack.us/img541/7903/svnlogsempty.png

Comment: There is no log in the Console View

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable Console output apparently.

In the toolbar select `Window` -> `Preferences`.

In preferences, select `Team` -> `SVN` -> `Console`.

In the `Show console automatically`, select `On output`.

Click OK.

After that you will be able to see what has changed upon SVN update in the SVN Console.

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> and then select the SVN Console.